# Angular HttpClient.post body format?

Tags: angular, formatting, http-post, angular-httpclient

Problem: server expects `grant_type=password&username=username&password=password`, however following code spits out exactly the same string **enclosed into double quotes**. i.e.: `"grant_type=password&username=username&password=password"`, which causes server to reject. I can't reimplement server's logic due to source code absence, so can I alter somehow default `HttpClient` formatting engine?..

```
const body = 
new HttpParams()
    .set('grant_type', 'password')
    .set('username', userName)
    .set('password', password)
    .toString();
// HttpClient post request with this body goes here
```

Comment: Skip the `.toString();` part, I guess.

Comment: @SiddAjmera, nope, in either case `.toString()` is called internally.

Comment: Is it? Please add your request code as well.

Comment: BTW, are you sure it's expecting this as `HttpParams` and not as `HttpHeaders`?

Comment: what is your `content-type`?

Comment: ah indeed, without `.toString()` it's ok, first time did not recompile properly and ran same broken code. thanks.